# How to make a Time difference for different phases for a particular work_item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In the following Image, I would like to make a time difference for a particular work_item for each and every phase

```
print (df)
         timestamp  work_item from_phase to_phase
0   1/2/2015 14:39  WI_000001      Start  Analyze
1   1/5/2015 11:48  WI_000001    Analyze   Design
2   1/5/2015 12:35  WI_000001     Design  Analyze
3   1/7/2015 11:04  WI_000001    Analyze   Deploy
4  1/27/2015 11:36  WI_000001     Deploy      End
5   1/2/2015 15:04  WI_000002      Start  Analyze
6   1/14/2015 9:46  WI_000002    Analyze   Design
7   1/14/2015 9:46  WI_000002     Design    Build
8   1/14/2015 9:46  WI_000002      Build      End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working if always next row starting by previous betwen `from_phase` and `to_phase` per groups.

First convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and create new column for differencies per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html).

Then remove fist `NaN`s rows per groups by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), aggregate `sum`, convert timedeltas to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['diff'] = df.groupby('work_item')['timestamp'].diff()

df = (df.dropna(subset=['diff'])
        .groupby(['work_item','from_phase'])['diff']
        .sum()
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='sum of differencies'))
print (df)

   work_item from_phase  sum of differencies
0  WI_000001    Analyze               416280
1  WI_000001     Deploy              1729920
2  WI_000001     Design                 2820
3  WI_000002    Analyze              1017720
4  WI_000002      Build                    0
5  WI_000002     Design                    0
```